# how to keep htaccess file under site root

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

localhost, xampp, win 7
site path:
`C:\xampp\htdocs\news\s02`

so all relevant files, including `.htaccess` is under `s02` folder.

links like this work fine:
`http://localhost/news/s02/view.php?art=160915142500&title=blue-sky`

I want the following computed url
`http://localhost/articles/160915142500/blue-sky`

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^articles/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z-_]*)$ view.php?art=$1&title=$2 [NC,L]
```

result - error 404

**httpd.conf**
`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` - uncommented
`AllowOverride All` - all instances

When I move `.htaccess` file to:
`C:\xampp\htdocs`
and change RewriteRule to:
`RewriteRule ^articles/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z-_]*)$ news/s02/view.php?art=$1&title=$2 [NC,L]`

there is no `error 404`, i.e. `view.php` is loaded, but without images, css and js files (they are all under previous, i.e. `s02` folder.

How to keep `.htaccess` file under site root (`s02`) and load `view.php` with all its elements?

restarting xampp and apache and mysql modules doesn't help.

Comment: add Rewrite rules for css,js folders also including `s02` folder

Comment: @yes_i_am_vj, RewriteRule for all depending files, including images... I think that's no way `.htaccess`works by default.

Comment: What I meant was you have to consider while ReWriting rule.. try like `RewriteRule .*               /news/s02/%1.%2          [L,NC]`

Comment: You are calling the URL from the root, like localhost/articles...so that way you need to have the .htaccess in that directory.

Comment: @user3571366, there is no any `articles` folder in my entire site. I just want `articles/` to be written inside url.

Comment: try `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /news/s02/$1 `

Comment: Like @user3571366 said, move your `.htaccess` file to `C:\xampp\htdocs` if you want to rewrite URLs that are outside of the `http://localhost/news/s02/` scope. How would Apache know it has to go to that folder when you try to rewrite something beginning with `articles`?

Comment: @bonaca still you need to have a htaccess file in the htdocs directory.

Comment: @Capsule, I tried, but `view.php...` is loaded without dependecies. Anyway, what about url without `articles/` part. Could you give me an example of usual practice. I just want a SEO friendly url, i.e. without `view.php?art=...`

Comment: Use absolute paths in your HTML to reference images, css, etc. Because when rewritten, the current "virtual" path is `/articles/160915142500/blue-sky`, not `/news/s02/`, so make sure to use paths like `/images/something.png` or `/css/stuff.css` instead of relative paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible to do from a sub directory. You are basically trying to rewrite a request sent to the root directory from within a sub directory. In order to rewrite the current url, apache should see the .htaccess file in the current directory.

However you can still redirect to the specified location, but you have to make the .htaccess file in the htdocs directory.

This is my first answer :) Not sure if this is suitable as an answer.

Comment: In this case this `.htaccess` will be working for all my local sites !

Comment: of course yes, that's why you need to use virtualhosts ;)

Comment: Could you explain pls. I don't want to use this `htaccess` for all sites but each site should have its own `htaccess` if any.

Comment: Setup virtualhosts. Google and you will find more.

Comment: or start rewriting from each project folder, but the prettiest URL you could get is `/news/s02/articles...`